# Android WebView SSL error on version 53 but not version 54

Tags: android, webview

I am using WebView within my app to view a simple web page using TLS/SSL.  For some reason, when my clients are using WebView version 53.0.2785, I get an SSL error in my custom web view client.

```
public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error)
```

The "SslError" is SSL_INVALID (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/SslError.html).  This seems to be some generic error that gets returned when the exact cause could not be determined.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwContentsClientBridge.java#164

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/SslUtil.java#38

However, if I get my clients to upgrade their WebView version to 54.0.x.x via Google Play, the error no longer appears.

I tried going through the changelist between WebView 53 -> 54 but nothing sticks out.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/master/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be affecting you again. I ran into this issue where 53 and 54 were reporting SSL Error due to a fault by Google, apparently what was making it work on 54 will expire by now too

https://search.thawte.fr/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=ALERT2162&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US

more info from Symmantec
https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/update-chrome-53-bug-affecting-symantec-ssltls-certificates

---